# RadioButton switch, case

Tags: android, java

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии определенного флага в RadioButton, формула вычислялась по другому и выводила это значение?

```
final double answerNoChoose = 6+(2.7*2)+(5*2)-(5.8*2);
    RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1)  
    radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(
            ) {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId){
            case 1:
                double answer = answerNoChoose*2;
                mOtvetTextView.setText(answer);
                break;
            case 2:
                double answerTwo = answerNoChoose*5;
                mOtvetTextView.setText(answerTwo);
                break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Вот полный код:

```
 package ru.tu.guide;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.RadioGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class trututut extends Activity {

TextView mOtvetTextView;
OnClickListener radioListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.status);
    mOtvetTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.otvet);

    EditText rostEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rost);
    EditText vesEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ves);
    EditText ageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    String rost = rostEditText.getText().toString();
    String ves = vesEditText.getText().toString();
    String age = ageEditText.getText().toString();
    int rost2 = Integer.parseInt(rost);
    int ves2 = Integer.parseInt(ves);
    int age2 = Integer.parseInt(age);
    final double answerNoChoose = 6+(2.7*2)+(5*2)-(5.8*2);

    RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(
            ) {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId){
            case 1:
                double answer = answerNoChoose*2;
                mOtvetTextView.setText(answer);
                break;
            case 2:
                double answerTwo = answerNoChoose*5;
                mOtvetTextView.setText(answerTwo);
                break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Не очень понятна проблема. Сейчас формула умножается на 2 или на 5, и не работает?

Comment: просто вылетает активность, эклипс не показывает ошибок, все вроде верно, но при выборе элемента RadioButton вылетает, обработчик просто не работает

Comment: У вас в `case` должен быть id `RadioButton`, а не эти непонятные числа типа 1 и 2.

Comment: и с id пробовал, вылетает, вообще не понимаю, переписал все, оставил RadioGrop и все, все формулы убрал, при нажатии тупо вылетает

Comment: лог и отладка что говорят?

Comment: Could not find a method onRadioClick(View) in the activity class *class* for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RadioButton witch id "radioLow"

как бы не меня все, 1 и та же ошибка, не может найти метод обработчика нажатия

Comment: хм. а можете выложить xml?

Comment: полагаю что нужно внутренние RadioButton создать и делать switch по их id